# Output dimension from transfer learning model incompatible

Tags: r, keras, deep-learning, transfer-learning

I have loaded the `cifar10` dataset in keras for r and have images of shape 32x32x3 with 10 labels.

```
library(keras)

c(train_images, train_labels) %<-% cifar$train
c(test_images, test_labels) %<-% cifar$test

train_images %>% dim # 50000    32    32     3
train_labels %>% dim # 50000    1
test_images %>% dim  # 50000    32    32     3
test_labels %>% dim  # 50000    1
length(unique(train_labels)) # 10
```

Now I have also loaded a pre-trained imagenet model and everything is cool up until training, I even confirm that I have exactly 10 labels, which are the number of classes I have.

```
conv_base <- keras::application_resnet101(weights = "imagenet",
                                          include_top = FALSE, 
                                          input_shape = c(32,32,3))


freeze_weights(conv_base)

model <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
  conv_base %>%
  layer_flatten() %>%
  layer_dense(units = 256, activation = "relu") %>%
  layer_dense(units = 10, activation = "softmax")


model %>% compile(
  optimizer = "adam",
  loss = "categorical_crossentropy",
  metrics = "accuracy"
)

# unfreeze_weights(conv_base, from = "block5_conv1")

history <- model %>% fit(
  x=train_images, y=train_labels, 
  validation_split = 0.3,
  epochs=10, 
  verbose = 2
)
```

the `summary(model)` tells me that the output is `10` as expected.

```
Model: "sequential_10"
__________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                        Output Shape                     Param #      
==================================================================================
resnet101 (Functional)              (None, 1, 1, 2048)               42658176     
__________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_5 (Flatten)                 (None, 2048)                     0            
__________________________________________________________________________________
dense_24 (Dense)                    (None, 256)                      524544       
__________________________________________________________________________________
dense_23 (Dense)                    (None, 10)                       2570         
==================================================================================
Total params: 43,185,290
Trainable params: 527,114
Non-trainable params: 42,658,176
```

But once I train, I get errors an error saying 1 isn't the same shape as the expected 10 on the output. The error is:

```
Epoch 1/10
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ValueError: in user code:
<... omitted ...> C:\Users\blake\ANACON~1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\blake\ANACON~1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\losses.py:1537 categorical_crossentropy
        return K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits)
    C:\Users\blake\ANACON~1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\blake\ANACON~1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py:4833 categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)
    C:\Users\blake\ANACON~1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py:1134 assert_is_compatible_with
        raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))

    ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 10) are incompatible

See `reticulate::py_last_error()` for details
```

Answer (score 0):

And I seem to have answered my own question... use `loss = sparse_categorical_crossentropy`.

```
model %>% compile(
  optimizer = "adam",
  loss = "sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
  metrics = "accuracy"
)
```